# Routing error - No route matches [GET] error using activerecord-reputation-system gem in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm going to add voting system to my rails application and I tried to run reputation-system using activerecord-reputation-system gem and followed [railscasts #364](http://railscasts.com/episodes/364-active-record-reputation-system?view=asciicast) video.

I'm struggling at the routing error, when I click on upvote or downvote, it shows an error "No route matches [GET] "/haikus/1/vote"

[image]
[image]

/config/routes.rb:

```
Youhaiku::Application.routes.draw do
  get 'signup', to: 'users#new', as: 'signup'
  get 'login', to: 'sessions#new', as: 'login'
  get 'logout', to: 'sessions#destroy', as: 'logout'

  resources :users
  resources :sessions
  resources :haikus do
    member { post :vote }
  end

  root to: 'haikus#index'
end
```

/app/controllers/haikus_controller.rb:

```
def vote
  value = params[:type] == "up" ? 1 : -1
  @haiku = Haiku.find(params[:id])
  @haiku.add_evaluation(:votes, value, current_user)
  redirect_to :back, notice: "Thank you for voting!"
end
```

/app/views/haikus/_haiku.html.erb:

```
<div class="haiku">
  <%= simple_format haiku.content %>
  <em>
    -- <%= haiku.user.name %>
    | <%= link_to "up", vote_haiku_path(haiku, type: "up"), method: "post" %>
    | <%= link_to "down", vote_haiku_path(haiku, type: "down"), method: "post" %>
  </em>
</div>
```

I checked out this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21644888/routing-error-in-activerecord-reputation-gem-in-rails-4) but this is not help me out. So, I really need help on this.

Comment: try this `<%= link_to "up", vote_haiku_path(haiku, type: "up"),  method: :post %>`

Comment: Yes, I have tried but it is not working for me !

Comment: can you paste the html you are getting after rendering this link.

Comment: When I click on "Upvote" link, getting the following error

Routing Error

No route matches [GET] "/haikus/1/vote"
Try running rake routes for more information on available routes.

Comment: Try this: `<a rel="nofollow" data-method="post" href="<%=vote_haiku_path(haiku, type: "up")%>"></a>`

Comment: tried the above one but it is not working, getting the same routing error :(

Comment: Your code is fine,though you getting an error. Very weird.

Comment: Only possible reason is jquery bug. Can you share your application.js and are you getting any js error in firebug?

Comment: // This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
// listed below.
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .

Comment: I'm not getting any js error, i checked with chrome console, only 404 not found error when I click on "Upvote" link

Comment: I downloaded and tried the same code from railcasts its working absolutely fine for me..

Comment: @PardeepDhingra Did you tried Up and Down voting ?

Comment: Yes i tried and its working absolutely fine for me. I have used `youhaiku-from-scratch` and `youhaiku-after` both working

Comment: Thanks a lot @PardeepDhingra for spending time with me. Let me try again and let you know !

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81174/discussion-between-diya-and-pardeep-dhingra).

Answer (score 0):

As can be seen from the error you are getting, you are sending GET request and Rails waiting for POST for this action. You need to ensure you generated a correct HTML with `link_to`.

To achieve this check if `data-method` on your link says "post". To do it you can right-click the up\down vote link and press inspect element.

If it is not there but your view partial says `method: "post"` try changing it to `method: :post` as Pardeep advised in comments.

Comment: even this is not working `<a rel="nofollow" data-method="post" href="<%=vote_haiku_path(haiku, type: "up")%>"></a>`

Comment: Please let us know what you get in HTML on the page

Comment: Getting the below html code 
<a rel="nofollow" data-method="post" href="/haikus/7/vote?type=up">Up</a>

Comment: I am getting this `<a href="/haikus/5/vote?value=1" data-method="post" rel="nofollow">up</a>`

Comment: I was able to reproduce it by commenting out `<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>` from my `app/views/layouts/application.rb`. Please check the headers your page with upvote links has.